# An online website that produces specific set of points that satisfy a given equation

Tags: math-software

My request is very simple. I am looking for an online website in which I can insert an equation and specifying the starting x value (example: 0) and I want it to generate 5 more points with a jump of 1 value. (x=1,2,3,4,5) with their y-values. You might think it is such a silly task but I really need it in case if want to generate 20 points or so and I want to do it quickly..

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are looking for, desmos.com will plot graphs for you, if you just want values, there are many options such as Python, Octave/Matlab, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Go to desmos.com/calculator (You may have to create a free account.)

(2) Click the plus sign in the upper left corner and select 'table' from drop down list.

(3) In the cell underneath $x_1$ enter the first $x$ value. (e.g $1.0$)

(4) In column $2$ replace the $y_1$ with the $x$ expression defining the function in terms of $x_1$ and hit return. You should see the correct first value of $y$ appear in the cell to the right of the initial $x$ value.

(5) In column one in the cell beneath the cell where you entered the first $x$ value, enter the value of $x+\Delta x$. (e.g. $1.2$) Hit return and the next value of $x$ will increment automatically and the corresponding $y$ value will appear as well.

(6) Continue until you have the desired number of values.

Comment: Make sure you define the function in terms of $x_1$ not $x$ or you will get an error message.

Comment: If you find my solution is what you need, please check the arrow beside your question to give me credit. I have been having a bad week with hardly anyone crediting me for a correct answer even when it was the only answer given.